# Is there anything to do at Mekar Island?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I traveled to Mekar Island during the day and noticed several piles of bones. I figured there might be a night event and so I lit a fire and waited till the evening. Sure enough, all the bones came to life. I thought something might happen if I defeated them, but nothing did.

I searched the area and couldn't find anything else to do. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently, there does not appear to be anything unique on this island.  It is simply a reference to the sage [Makar](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Makar) from the Wind Waker (according to the [Wiki](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Mekar_Island)).

There are a few other sites that discuss the island, none of which have found anything interesting:

- [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75096667)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/5yjwuo/mekar_island/)

Besides the enemies found at night here, there is nothing else to the island.  According to the Reddit source above, this is also a possible reference to the very first dungeon in the original Zelda game:

> I think it's a reference to the first ever Zelda dungeon, Level 1. There's a dead tree, and four piles of bones in place of the surrounding four smaller trees

Here is a screenshot of what they mean:

[image: Zelda dungeon]

<sub><sub>Image source from linked Reddit above.</sub></sub>

There is also [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84Tuuzn-zko) of someone exploring the island at night.  They take out all the enemies, and walk around some, but don't find anything unusual otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is specific to Mekar Island, but you can also cut the grass. This is easier to do with a one handed sword, and through this it's possible to find about 5 fairies, which are useful for healing potions. However, I haven't found anything unique, like little people with korok seeds or anything, but it would be interesting if there was a secret that everyone was missing. So far, I cant see one myself. :)

Answer (score 4):

Mekar Island is actually a hiding spot for some faeries. If you have fewer than 4 faeries and you start cutting grass on the island, you should be able to find enough to get you back up to 4-5.

Comment: Hi Erik, I edited your answer so it's not just a comment on someone else's answer. This way it can stand on its own. Feel free to change it around if you feel I put words into your mouth.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the few locations you can find stealthfin trout in abundance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something it is the campfire it won't go out in rain I discovered this when I got rushed by the stals. I think the stals respawn if you don't kill them in a set time, because a blood moon randomly happened even though one just happened 3 nights ago.

Answer (score 0):

Mekar island is a homage to Makar the sage. He was a korok boy who helped link in Wind Waker. Its believed that Makar left link and went to the island and grew up and eventually died there. If you climb up and stand ontop then wind will blow very fast. This is like link playing the wind waker.

Comment: I tested this and you're right, it does start blowing a lot when you do that, and stop as soon as you jump down! That's pretty neat.

Answer (score -1):

I sat at the campfire till morning, and a bunch of chuchus spawned as a result after wandering around a little. I think the island is more like a spawning ground for large gatherings of small fry enemies? I was able to farm a bunch of electric chu jellies by killing the chus with lightning arrows.