# Can't leave Mekar Island

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was traveling from the Tabantha Stable to get the Sheikah tower in the region between that and Death Mountain (haven't explored this region yet).  I attempted to cross a river and ended up landing on an island in the middle of it.  From a map I found online, this island is called Mekar Island.

[image: Mekar Island]

When I landed on the island, some Chuchus swarmed me...and that was it.  There is a lone rock on the island next to a tall dead tree and an unlit campfire.  I lifted the rock (no Korok Seed), found a Flint, lit the fire and nothing happened.  So I decided to leave the island and glided over to the other side.  I started climbing the steep riverbank when the screen started to fade to white and I was teleported back to the island (Link then looked around kind of perplexed).  I tried again using Revali's Gale to get even higher up and it teleported me mid glided.

I'm not sure if this is some sort of glitch because Link did look around confused like it he was programmed to do that, but I haven't found any sort of challenge on the island to complete or anyone else on the internet mentioning this same issue.  I haven't tried to Fast Travel yet in case there is a challenge there also (don't want to make the trek back).

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I hadn't tried that last night, partly because I needed to go to bed and partly because I was focused on getting to that tower.  I'll try to go back to the other bank of the river real quick during my lunch break and comment again.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you keep going in the direction of the Lost Woods and are succumbing to the fog.  As @Yuuki said the fog is meant to teleport you back the way you came.  Instead of heading east I would recommend heading west if you actually want to leave the island.

Comment: @Yuuki I was able to try this yesterday and you were right, I was trying to go into the Lost Woods.  I started exploring them shortly after escaping by going in the correct entrance and the teleport of going the wrong way was the same thing I had been seeing.  Thank you, and thank you @BlueBarren!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So Mekar Island is rather close to the Lost Woods. If you get too close to the Lost Woods when approaching from the incorrect direction, you will be teleported back. Instead of heading eastwards, head west and go south along the opposite shore.

Comment: @bubbajake00 also seems curious about the significance of Mekar Island. Timmy Jim suggests in [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/306517/65440) that "Currently, there does not appear to be anything unique on this island. It is simply a reference to the sage Makar from the Wind Waker"